# Extracting a range of co-ordinates from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 100x100x100 numpy array that represents a 3D volume made up of 2D slices.

I want to carry out cross correlation of an object in this volume on a bunch of these volumes using a template created from the volume with the best signal to noise.

To make things easier I am trying to do 2D cross correlation and then just building up the 3D volume by doing scipy correlate2d on each slice and then putting that slice into a 3D numpy array.

I have tested the correlate2d function and that all seems to work fine however I want the ability to pull out any part of any one of these slices and make that my template according to measured co-ordinates.

```
#inputdata, a 3D numpy array with x , y and z image data.
mrc = np.array((mrcfileinput.data))

#The measured coords for the template I want to box out
xtake = np.array(range(64,77))
ytake = np.array([50])
ztake = np.array(range(9,32))

#checking the range is correct
print (xtake, ytake, ztake)

#turning them into lists although not sure this is needed
xlist = list(xtake)
ylist = list(ytake)
zlist = list(ztake)

#attempting to implement numpy.take with very little luck
template = np.take(mrc, ([xlist],[ylist],[zlist]))

print (template)
```

So my initial idea was to measure the two corners of the box I want to box out. This is essentially a 2D box (the y axis remains at 50). This does not seem to play nice with the numpy take command. Before I go away and think about how to populate an entire array with every single exact co-ordanite that is needed that I think is what the take command wants I was wondering if anyone knew of an easier way?

(turning everything into lists was to make it comma separated. I am not sure this is actually needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you want to take a 2D box out of a 3D array. If you want the 2D box to be expressed still as a 3D array with one axis which is of length one, you can use:

```
template = mrc[64:77, 50:51, 9:32]  # shape (13, 1, 23)
```

If instead you really want just a 2D array, this simplifies to:

```
template = mrc[64:77, 50, 9:32]  # shape (13, 23)
```

Hope this helps.